# Export EGit preferences

Tags: eclipse, egit

Is there a way to export the git preferences (what's under Preferences > Team > Git) to an external file for other team members to import? I don't mean the git configuration, but things like History > Show all branches and tags. Export... > Preferences > Export all doesn't export the git preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Export Preferences wizard with "Export all" works here, the resulting `.epf` file contains settings for `org.eclipse.egit.*`. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not contain git URIs. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can make a backup of the internal EGit configuration file from /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.egit.ui/dialog_settings.xml